# Android horizontal progressBar not updating progress

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using facebook graph request for uplaoding video. This api has onProgressCallback method which gives current bytes written and maximum bytes that can be written for a file as follows:

```
@Override
public void onProgress(final long current, final long max) {
    if (isFirstLoad) {
        progressBarHorizonatl.setProgress(0);
        progressBarHorizonatl.setMax((int) max);
        isFirstLoad = false;
    }
    progressBarHorizontal.setProgress((int) current);
}
```

this method is called repeatedly while uploading the video but progress bar is not updated. It will get updated at the last call only. Can anyone help me what might be the problem.

Comment: Do you use `AsyncTask` for downloading?

Comment: Facebook api itself will do a task  asynchronously. And it will give a progress callback on UI thread

Comment: Might have something to do with current and max being long, while you cast it to int.
Is it possible values range from 0.0l to 1.0l (in that case int of current is always 0)? Does current change?

Comment: Please share your log.

Comment: E/Progress Log:42/23225734
        E/Progress Log:399/23225734
        E/Progress Log:619/23225734
        E/Progress Log:666/23225734
        E/Progress Log:676/23225734
        E/Progress Log:1036/23225734
        E/Progress Log:1086/23225734
        E/Progress Log:1108/23225734
        E/Progress Log:1139/23225734
        E/Progress Log:23225688/23225734
        E/Progress Log:23225732/23225734
        E/Progress Log:23225734/23225734

Answer (score 0):

Update ProgressBar on UI thread. Try attached code.

```
@Override
public void onProgress(final long current, final long max) {
    if (isFirstLoad) {
        progressBarHorizonatl.setProgress(0);
        progressBarHorizonatl.setMax((int) max);
        isFirstLoad = false;
    }
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
                            progressBarHorizontal.setProgress((int) current);
                        }
                    });

}
```

Comment: onProgress itself is running  on main thread  i.e  is also the ui thread then why  to use handler

Comment: asynchronous task runs on different thread. That's you need handler to send data to Main UI thread.

Try once and let me know if it works for you

Comment: onProgress of facebook graph api runs on ui thread. This is not the progress of android asynctask.